# Add item to a Jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have already looked at some array topics but I am still stumped.

I wish to add a new line to my jagged array - and am strugigng to get the syntax right..

```
        int[][] intJaggedArray = new int[7][];

        intJaggedArray[0] = new int[3] { 1, 1, 1 };
        intJaggedArray[1] = new int[3] { 2, 2, 2 };
        intJaggedArray[2] = new int[3] { 3, 3, 3 };
        intJaggedArray[3] = new int[3] { 4, 4, 4 };
        intJaggedArray[4] = new int[3] { 5, 5, 5 };
        intJaggedArray[5] = new int[3] { 6, 6, 6 };
        intJaggedArray[6] = new int[3] { 7, 7, 7 };
```

So now if i want to add

```
        intJaggedArray[0] = new int[3] { 1, 1, 2 };
```

so the array ends up being as shown below how do I acheive it - thanks in advance - A noob from England. (And a big thanks in advance)

```
        intJaggedArray[0] = new int[3] { 1, 1, 1 };
        intJaggedArray[0] = new int[3] { 1, 1, 2 };
        intJaggedArray[1] = new int[3] { 2, 2, 2 };
        intJaggedArray[2] = new int[3] { 3, 3, 3 };
        intJaggedArray[3] = new int[3] { 4, 4, 4 };
        intJaggedArray[4] = new int[3] { 5, 5, 5 };
        intJaggedArray[5] = new int[3] { 6, 6, 6 };
        intJaggedArray[6] = new int[3] { 7, 7, 7 };
```

Comment: The "so the array ends up being as shown" part is not very clear. What do those `**` markers mean?  Your current code is OK for replacing the first array.

Comment: It was the bold in the editor going bad/wrong - Unintended.

Comment: After your edit your sample still has 2 rows at index 0. Maybe state clearly: Replace a row or Insert a row ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to do? Insert a line between 0 and 1? Or replace the existing line 0?

Your line :

```
intJaggedArray[0] = new int[3] { 1, 1, 2 };
```

simply replaces the existing line 0.

You can't insert a line in an array. To do so, use a list instead:

```
List<int[]> myList = new List<int[]>();
myList.Add(new int[] {...});
myList.Add(new int[] {...});
myList.Add(new int[] {...});

...

myList.Insert(1, new int[] {...});
```

Or if you want to replace the existing line, then simply:

Comment: Thanks guys, this was great - I will try a list.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to create a collection or a `List<int[]>`

Then you could insert an item into it at a certain index.

```
List<int[]> x = new List<int[]>();
x.Insert(3, new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the initial list to be of a variable length, you cannot use an array. Use a List instead.

This should work:

```
List<int[]> intJaggedList = new List<int[]>();
intJaggedList.Add( new int[3] { 1, 1, 1 } );
intJAggedList.Add( new int[3] { 2, 2, 2 } );
...
```

Then to insert your new array:

```
intJaggedList.Insert( 1, new int[3] { 1, 1, 2 } );
```